# NameError : name 'pack' is not defined

Tags: python, module

I made a simple code myself but it doesn't work in any python IDE such as pycharm and Wing IDE. But it works properly in terminal.

In IDE, it keeps occuring error "NameError: name 'pack' is not defined"

I'm using kali linux.

I've already tried checking struct.py file

```
from struct import *

packed_data = pack("iif", 6, 19, 4.73)
print(packed_data)
```

## construct.py code

```
__all__ = [
# Functions
'calcsize', 'pack', 'pack_into', 'unpack', 'unpack_from',
'iter_unpack',

# Classes
'Struct',

# Exceptions
'error'
]

from _struct import *
from _struct import _clearcache
from _struct import __doc__
```

Comment: I edited and sorry I'm not used to stackoverflow

Comment: @Colin Can you just verify if you can just do import struct on python inbuilt ide because your code works on my system

Comment: @Colin also check the python version

Comment: @Doodle When I type import struct also pops up. I don't see any problem in my code and module. Mine is 3.7.3

Comment: @Colin here is the output I'm getting  b'\x06\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00)\\\x97@'

Comment: @Colin can you just open terminal and type python / python3 and do the same code there and see if there is the same problem or not

Comment: @Doodle I did the same code in terminal and it works properly. The error only occurs in IDE application

Comment: I think i now why, because you have a module called `struct` in the folder

Comment: That which doesn't contain a function called `pack`

Comment: @U10-Forward Very likely

Comment: @U10-Forward In which folder you mean?

Comment: @Colin In the folder where your code is

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to keep filename as struct.py because "struct" is module in python. Try once again by changing filename.